# Python Spark split list into sublists divided by the sum of value inside elements

Tags: python, mapreduce, aggregate-functions, partitioning, apache-spark

I try to split a list of objects in python into sublists based on the cumulative value of one of the parameters in the object. Let me present it on the example:

I have a list of objects like this:

```
[{x:1, y:2}, {x:3, y:2}, ..., {x:5, y: 1}]
```

and I want to divide this list into sub-lists where the total sum of x values inside a sublist will be the same (or roughly the same) so the result could look like this:

```
[[{x:3, y:1}, {x:3, y:1}, {x:4, y:1}], [{x:2, y:1}, {x:2, y:1}, {x:6, y:1}]]
```

Where the sum of x'es is equal to 10. Objects I am working with are a little bit more complicated, and my x'es are float values. So I want to aggregate the values from the ordered list, up till the sum of x'es will be >= 10, and then start creating next sub-list.

In my case, the first list of elements is an ordered list, and the summation has to take place on the ordered list.

I done something like this already in C#, where I iterate through all my elements, and keep one counter of "x" value. I sum the value of x for consecutive objects, until it will hit my threshold, and then I create a new sub-list, and restart my counter.

Now I want to reimplement it in python, and next use it with [Spark](http://spark.apache.org). So I am looking for a little bit more "functional" implementation, maybe something to work nicely with map-reduce framework. I can't figure out another way than the iterative approach.

If you have any suggestions, or possible solutions, I would welcome all constructive comments.

Comment: Do you need to preserve ordering in the split process? When looking into parellelizing this algo, we need a way to partition the data. In this case, applying a naive split on the source data might create 'leftovers' that could leave some elements out of their target set.

Comment: @maasg I need to preserve ordering in my initial list, because it is important for me to add together the values from consecutive samples. My dataset is a set of samples describing the change of parameter x in time. Now I want to group samples together with roughly equal value of x, and to do so, I need to add them together and keep them in the same order, to still have meaningful data.

Comment: I gave a shot at a functional impl here: https://gist.github.com/maasg/89be8b089cdb012ffbd8 but I didn't find a way around order preservation. So the algo is pretty much sequential as a iterative solution would be. Even worst, when trying to avoid keeping mutable state, this solution is O(n^2) while a simple iterator with a cummulater over the elements is O(n). For a "sparky" solution, you will need a way to partition the data, so keeping order might be a tough requirement.

Comment: if `x` is a delta value, could the absolute value be used? Looking at  parallelization, is there a way to split the set in two? (And then maybe again in two to attempt a tree-like structure) ?

Comment: Maybe I mixed up a little bit the problem. I guess I don't need to preserver the ordering on the final list. I just need to process the initial list in the ordered way. So if the required value of x could be found by adding first 10 elements in the list, thats what I need.

Comment: Would you have a way to split the input sequence? Looks like they need to be in ordered sequence, right?

Comment: Yes, order of input sequence is vital. I guess it makes it impossible to partition it right?

Comment: I think so. If respecting the input order is mandatory, there's no way to parallelize that process. But if there's no need to preserve order further down the process, it's possible to serialize the initial computation and parallelize the computation afterwards although that will fall outside the ctx of this question.